# Quando usar module.exports ou exports no Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou começando meus estudo com Node e me deparei com as duas maneiras de se exportar algo para que fique disponivel com o `require`, gostaria de saber qual é a melhor forma e por que.

Obrigado

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Por natureza ambos `exports` e `module.exports` apontam para o mesmo objeto. Assim se adicionares propriedades a um deles ambos vão receber essa propriedade pois apontam para o mesmo objeto.

Na prática o que o NodeJS (modulos CommonJS) faz é:

```
var module = { exports: {} };
var exports = module.exports;

// aqui escreves o código no ficheiro do modulo.
// as linhas que eu coloquei aqui (antes e depois) o NodeJS faz automáticamente
// e nem precisas de as escrever ou pensar nelas

return module.exports;
```

Assim se criares uma nova propriedade no `module.exports` ela vai estar acessível via `exports` pois apontam para o mesmo objeto. Ou seja:

```
module.exports.foo = 'bar';
console.log(exports.foo); // 'bar'
```

Há contudo uma diferênça crucial: deves ter em conta que quando requeres um modulo o que é retornado é o `module.exports`. Isso quer dizer que se re-atribuíres `module.exports` com um novo valor, objeto ou função,  o `require` não vai referenciar isso. Por exemplo dentro de um ficheiro `script.js` se tiveres este código:

```
console.log(module.exports == exports); // dá true
module.exports = 'foo';
exports = 'bar';
```

Aí quando fizeres `require` desse modulo o que é exportado é o `module.exports` e não o `export`, pois re-atribuíste novos valores a essas variáveis/propriedades e por natureza do NodeJS/CommonJS o que é exportado é `module.exports`. Assim vais ter isto:

```
var foo = require('./script.js');
console.log(typeof foo, foo);          // string 'foo', e não 'bar' que tinhas defenido no exports
```

Se queres usar modulos deves exportar com `module.exports`. Se quiseres exportar mais do que uma função/objeto/variável deves fazer:

```
module.exports = {
    get: function(){ ... },
    set: function(){ ... }
}
```