# Ajuda com exercício

Tags: javascript

Alguém pode me ajudar a corrigir este exercício? Estou tentando finalizar estas linhas e não consigo:

---

```
module.exports = function restaurantBill(bill) {

/*
  1. Crie uma variável chamada tax (imposto em inglês) e atribua-lhe o resultado
  de multiplique a conta em 10%.
*/

var tax = restaurantBill*0.10;

/*
  2. Crie uma variável chamada total e atribua-lhe o resultado da adição de conta
  mais impostos
*/


var total = restaurantBill+tax/5;

/*
  3. Retorne o valor que cada um deve pagar (total dividido por 5), com o
  símbolo $ antes (por exemplo: $ 11).
*/

return "$"+total;
};
```

Observações:

Imagine que você saiu para comer com seus quatro melhores amigos. A conta total de consumo é de 50 reais, mas para isso você deve adicionar 10% de imposto. Você quer dividir a conta igualmente entre os cinco.

Para isso você criou este programa.

Siga as etapas abaixo para completar o programa e determinar quanto deve pagar cada um.

- Crie uma variável chamada tax (imposto em inglês) e atribua-lhe o resultado de multiplique a conta em 10%. Dica: 10% em decimal é escrito 0,10.
- Crie uma variável chamada total e atribua-lhe o resultado da adição de conta mais impostos
- Retorne o valor que cada um deve pagar (total dividido por 5), com o símbolo $ antes (por exemplo: $ 11). Dica: você deve usar a cadeia de caracteres (concatenação de strings) para imprimir com o símbolo $ adiante.

Exemplo:

```
var output = restaurantBill(50);
console.log(output); // --> $11
```

Comment: tem parte q deveria ser do comentario, mas n está com o // pra escapar do resto dos comandos

Comment: Dá algum erro na tela?
Um detalhe interessante é em ``restaurantBill+tax/5``, que deve ser ``(restaurantBill+tax)/5`` (senão ele vai fazer tax/5 e depois somar restaurantBill. Ou ainda colocar a divisão em ``return "$"+total/5;``

Comment: Não deixe de marcar a pergunta escolhida como aceita. Veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e veja porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: Olá Pessoal! Graças a Vocês consegui finalizar e identificar o meu erro! Muito obrigada! Abraço!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você cometeu alguns erros no seu código, mas nada que seja para se flagelar.

1. Você não precisa usar o `module.export` no seu código por momento, ainda mais para um exercício tão simples.
2. Veja que ao fazer os cálculos, ao invés de chamar o parâmetro da função que seria `(bill)` você esta chamando a própria função em si.
3. Quando for fazer contas onde haja uma mutiplicação ou uma divisão e você precise atribuir uma taxa ao valor total antes de dividi-lo, não se esqueça de usar parenteses, para que ele faça a adição primeiro antes da divisão.

   `var total = (bill + tax) / 5;`
4. De mais você estava no caminho correto, so faltou atribuir uma nova variável para receber o resultado de retorno da função e depois apresenta-lo via `console.log`.

Segue o código abaixo, abraços.

```
   function restaurantBill(bill) {

/*
    1. Crie uma variável chamada tax (imposto em inglês) e atribua-lhe o resultado
    de multiplique a conta em 10%.
*/

var tax = bill * 0.10;

/*
    2. Crie uma variável chamada total e atribua-lhe o resultado da adição de conta
    mais impostos
*/

var total = (bill + tax) / 5;

/*
    3. Retorne o valor que cada um deve pagar (total dividido por 5), com o
    símbolo $ antes (por exemplo: $ 11).
*/

return "$" + total;
};

var output = restaurantBill(50);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Olá Pessoal! Graças a Vocês consegui finalizar e identificar o meu erro! Muito obrigada! Abraço!

Answer (score 4):

Você está usando a própria função para fazer o cálculo! Para obter o retorno certo, você deve passar nas fórmulas o parâmetro que a função recebe, que no caso é  `bill`.

Corrigindo seu código, ficaria:

```
module.exports = function restaurantBill(bill) {

    /*
      1. Crie uma variável chamada tax (imposto em inglês) e atribua-lhe o resultado
      de multiplique a conta em 10%.
    */

    var tax = bill*0.10;

    /*
      2. Crie uma variável chamada total e atribua-lhe o resultado da adição de conta
      mais impostos
    */


    var total = (bill+tax)/5;

    /*
      3. Retorne o valor que cada um deve pagar (total dividido por 5), com o
      símbolo $ antes (por exemplo: $ 11).
    */

    return "$"+total;
};
```

Comment: var total = (bill+tax)/5;

Comment: Verdade @LeoCaracciolo! Tinha apenas copiado o código, vou alterar aqui! (:

Comment: Outra coisa, como se faz para chamar a função?

Comment: você pode chama-la da seguinte forma: `restaurantBill(20)` dentro do script!

Comment: Acredito que vá dar um erro `message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined",`

Comment: Sim, terá que fazer um `import { restaurantBill } from 'nome-arquivo';` correto?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55084/quando-usar-module-exports-ou-exports-no-node-js

Comment: Olá Pessoal! Graças a Vocês consegui finalizar e identificar o meu erro! Muito obrigada! Abraço!

Answer (score 2):

Erros na sua função: Usando a própria função nos cálculos.

**Ao invés de**  `var tax = restaurantBill*0.10;`

**pode ser** `var tax = restaurantBill.arguments[0]*0.10;`

**Ao invés de**  `var total = restaurantBill+tax/5;`

**pode ser** `var total = (restaurantBill.arguments[0]+tax)/5;`

<sub>Eu digo `"pode"` porque há outra alternativa a exemplo das outras repostas aqui publicadas. Mas achei que deveria ampliar o leque de opções.</sub>

> Quando uma função recebe valores de parâmetro da instrução que invoca a função, esses valores de parâmetro são atribuídos silenciosamente à propriedade `arguments` do objeto function. Essa propriedade é um array de valores, com o valor de cada parâmetro sendo atribuído a uma entrada de índice baseado em zero no array - mesmo que não haja parâmetros definidos. Você poderá usar a notação de array (nomeFunção.arguments[i]) para extrair os valores de quaisquer parâmetros que desejar.

Veja o exemplo abaixo onde os parâmetros são valor e quantidade de pessoas

```js
function restaurantBill(bill) {

   return "$"+((restaurantBill.arguments[0]+(restaurantBill.arguments[0]*.10)))/restaurantBill.arguments[1];

};
console.log (restaurantBill(50,5));
```

A seguir seu script funcionando:

```js
    function restaurantBill(bill) {
        /*
          1. Crie uma variável chamada tax (imposto em inglês) e atribua-lhe o resultado
          de multiplique a conta em 10%.
        */
        var tax = restaurantBill.arguments[0]*0.10;
        
        /*
          2. Crie uma variável chamada total e atribua-lhe o resultado da adição de conta
          mais impostos
        */


        var total = (restaurantBill.arguments[0]+tax)/5;

        /*
          3. Retorne o valor que cada um deve pagar (total dividido por 5), com o
          símbolo $ antes (por exemplo: $ 11).
        */
        
         return "$"+total;

    };
    var output = restaurantBill(50);
    console.log(output); // --> $11
```

**Outra forma:**

```js
    function restaurantBill(bill) {
        /*
          1. Crie uma variável chamada tax (imposto em inglês) e atribua-lhe o resultado
          de multiplique a conta em 10%.
        */
        var tax = bill*0.10;
        
        /*
          2. Crie uma variável chamada total e atribua-lhe o resultado da adição de conta
          mais impostos
        */


        var total = (bill+tax)/5;

        /*
          3. Retorne o valor que cada um deve pagar (total dividido por 5), com o
          símbolo $ antes (por exemplo: $ 11).
        */
        
         return "$"+total;

    };
    var output = restaurantBill(50);
    console.log(output); // --> $11
```

A sintaxe formal para uma função é a seguinte:

```
 function nomeFunção ( [parâmetro] ....[parâmetro]) {
    instrução(ões)
 }
```

Os parâmetros (também conhecidos como argumentos) oferecem um mecanismo para "entregar" um valor de uma instrução para outra por meio de uma chamada de função.

Quando uma função recebe parâmetros, ela atribui os valores recebidos aos nomes de variável especificados nos parentesis da definição da função.

Considere o seguinte segmento de script:

```
function restaurantBill(bill) {
 alerta(bill);
}
restaurantBill("Yra Rodrigues");
```

Após a função ser definida no script, a próxima instrução chama essa mesma função, passando uma string (`Yra Rodrigues`) como parâmetro. A definição da função atribui automaticamente a string à variavel `bill`. Portanto, antes que a instrução alert() dentro da função seja executada, `bill` é avaliada como `Yra Rodrigues`

> **Conclusão:** use `bill` e não `restaurantBill` dentro da função!!!
>
> errado `bill+tax/5;` vai somar bill com a divisão de tax por 5
>
> correto `(bill+tax)/5;` vai dividir por 5 a soma de bill + tax

***sem muitas delongas pode-se fazer assim***

```js
function restaurantBill(bill) {

   return "$"+((bill+(bill*.10)))/5;

};
console.log (restaurantBill(50));
```

Comment: Creio que atribuir a função à uma variável possa acabar confundindo mais ainda alguém que está começando os estudos em Javascript.

Comment: Tanto faz, ela fez isso na chamada da função `var output = restaurantBill(50);`

Comment: Olá Pessoal! Graças a Vocês consegui finalizar e identificar o meu erro! Muito obrigada! Abraço!

Answer (score 1):

Você estava chamando a função dentro dela mesma, e na hora da divisão não fez a soma antes, confira agora se da certo:

```
var module = function restaurantBill(bill) {
    /*
      1. Crie uma variável chamada tax (imposto em inglês) e atribua-lhe o resultado
      de multiplique a conta em 10%.
    */

    var tax = bill*0.10;

    /*
      2. Crie uma variável chamada total e atribua-lhe o resultado da adição de conta
      mais impostos
    */

    var total = bill+tax;

    /*
      3. Retorne o valor que cada um deve pagar (total dividido por 5), com o
      símbolo $ antes (por exemplo: $ 11).
    */

    var result = "$ "+(total/5);

    return result;
};
```

Comment: Isso! Trocando o **restaurantBill** por **bill** resolve o problema. E a correção na divisão, claro.

Comment: como se faz para chamar a função?

Comment: chama o  `module()` dentro do `<script>`

Comment: Olá Pessoal! Graças a Vocês consegui finalizar e identificar o meu erro! Muito obrigada! Abraço!